# Chef knife issue with ssh command

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I am trying to do ssh to my servers using knife command by running below command:

```
knife ssh "name:myserverhost" "pwd"
```

But it throws me with below error:

```
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1637:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate net-ssh-gateway-1.2.0, because net-ssh-2.2.2 conflicts with net-ssh (>= 2.6.5) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:746:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:51:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:50:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:50:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-multi-1.1/lib/net/ssh/multi/session.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-multi-1.1/lib/net/ssh/multi.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.14.2/lib/chef/knife/ssh.rb:27:in `block in <class:Ssh>'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.14.2/lib/chef/knife.rb:204:in `call'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.14.2/lib/chef/knife.rb:204:in `load_deps'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.14.2/lib/chef/knife.rb:165:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.14.2/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:123:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/knife:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/knife:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/knife:23:in `<main>'
```

I am new to chef and knife, trying to run basic `pwd` command using knife ssh, can you please help me out what is the issue here?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way install `knife` for use on a workstation is to use the ChefDK installer packages. You have installed it as a gem which is both not a great idea in general ("unsupported" in the context of "we can't help as much because it's harder to debug issues") and also you are using a very old version of Ruby we stopped supporting long ago.

Remove your gem-installed version of Chef and install ChefDK and you should be all set.

Comment: Can you please provide me a link where I can get the steps to install it.